# Problem when plotting points on shiny R with eventReactive

Tags: r, shiny

This is my first post here so I hope I can explain my problem clearly. I am currently getting into shiny and want to start off by doing basic stuff. I decided to challenge myself by making an app that takes two numeric inputs and plots them whenever I press an actionbar. The problem is that I want to keep the previous points that I plot. I can't get it to work as it keeps resetting the plot. I've tried many different ways and I dont really know how points() works on shiny. Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId="execute",label="Execute"),
  numericInput(inputId="numY",label="Y",value=0),
  numericInput(inputId="numX",label="X",value=0),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  coordx <- eventReactive(input$execute,{input$numX})
  coordy <- eventReactive(input$execute,{input$numY})
  
  if(!exists("input$execute"))
  {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      plot(x=coordx(),y=coordy())
    })
  }
  else
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      points(x=coordx(),y=coordy())
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect your problem is not `points()` but your `eventReactive()`s.  I think you should use a single `reactive` instead.  This `reactive` should augment a `data.frame` with a new row of data each time your `actionButton` is clicked.  Welcome to SO, by the way.

Comment: Your `eventReactive` will overwrite the coordinate variables every time you change the input. You should consider caching the coordinate variables in a vector/list and only add the value if not already present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters @Limey and @fvall said, the issue seems to be the `eventReactive()` which overwrites each time. What I did instead is place the x and y coordinates in a `reactiveValues()`. Then I placed an `observeEvent()` for any time `input$execute` was pressed, writing the x and y coordinates to update the `reactiveValues()`. This will keep both the old and new values. I also added a little `tableOutput()` just to keep track of the values:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId="execute",label="Execute"),
  numericInput(inputId="numY",label="Y",value=0),
  numericInput(inputId="numX",label="X",value=0),
  plotOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("TABLE")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  coord<-reactiveValues("x" = NULL, "y" = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$execute, {
    req(input$numY, input$numX)
      tempx<-c(isolate(coord$x), input$numX)
      tempy<-c(isolate(coord$y), input$numY)
      coord$x <- tempx
      coord$y <- tempy
  })
  
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      req(input$execute)
      plot(x=isolate(coord$x),y=isolate(coord$y))
    })
    
    output$TABLE<-renderTable({
      data.frame("x" = coord$x, "y" = coord$y)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Best of luck! Though I had hiccups along the way, I really enjoyed learning Shiny myself, and I hope you do too!